# VNC viewer showing Blue Screen with Clock only

Tags: centos, vnc, vncviewer

I am trying to access my centos machine through VNC viewer after sucessfull login its showing blue screen with one clock ,Just for your reference see below image

[image]

Not sure what wrong with the setup. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: It looks as if you have only started `xclock` and nothing else. What other programs were expecting to show up?

Comment: Looks like twm.  Can you right click on the desktop?  Also, X as root is a bad idea.

Comment: Right click not giving any menu option.

Comment: @Kusalananda No i didnt start any program .

Answer (score 1):

install below package and restart VNC services

```
yum install gnome* --exclude=gnome-session-wayland-session
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a sentence or two to describe that the user is seeing a bare-bones X11 session with no desktop environment or window manager at all, which is very minimal to the point of being unusable.

Comment: I have symptoms like half-cut firefox windows and a cursor shows "X".  turns out I deleted gnome somehow. Thanks.